# Slidetoggle bug on jquery 1.12.4

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

i recently update my website, with a new jquery version. But this creat a bug in a small Jquery script i have write. My syntax should be bad for the last version. 
Thanks for helping me, this is the code:

```
//-----------------------XX-- + & - BOX--XX---------------
$('.texte , #devis_hide').css( 'display','none');
$('.plus , #plus_bis').css('cursor','pointer').toggle(
    function() {$(this).next().slideToggle(400); this.src = this.src.replace("plus","moins");},
    function() {$(this).next().slideToggle(400);this.src = this.src.replace("moins","plus"); }
);
```

The concept is really simple, an  + or - that deploy the  just next to him.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle is now deprecated and do not have the same effect, so i replace my code by this one:

```
$('.texte , #devis_hide').css( 'display','none')

$('.plus, #plus_bis').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).next().is(':visible') ) {
     $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("moins","plus"))
  } else {
     $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("plus","moins"))
  }
  $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
})
```